# Best way to apply formatting to a DateTime property in a view, when the class is not the view model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When the class is the view model, it seems like this is the way to do it:

```
public class Model 
{
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
   public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

and then use @Html.DisplayFor() in the view:

```
<div>The date is @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MyDate)</div>
```

In my case I'm looping through an array like this:

```
@foreach(var topic in topics)
    {
    <tr>
        <td><a asp-controller="Topic" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@topic.Id">@topic.Subject</a> by @topic.Firstpost.User.UserName (@topic.Firstpost.PostStamp)</td>
        <td class="number">@topic.RepliesCount</td>
        <td class="number">@topic.ViewCount TOPIC TYPE: @topic.GetType()</td>
        <td>by @topic.LastPost.User.UserName (@topic.LastPost.PostStamp)</td>
    </tr>
    }
```

The Topic class is not the model class, so using @Html.DisplayFor() is not an option.
What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Create a partial view for that part of the page, using the type in `topic` for it's model.

Answer (score 0):

Use string.Format instead:

```
<td>@string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", topic.topicDate)</td>
```

Comment: or something like _@topic.topicDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")_

Comment: @DanielSchmid Right. It's better to use ToString.